# How to disable the Issues pane in Qt Creator?

Tags: ide, qt-creator

I find it easier to work with compiler output but the Issues pane in the Qt Creator pops up automatically after every compilation, hiding the useful information, forcing me to hide it every time. Is there a way to disable this behavior? I don't mind the errors being collected, I just don't want this particular piece of UI to show up every time when I don't ask for it.

I'm using the Qt Creator 3.5.0 but it was like that in the earlier versions, too.

Comment: Argh this is sooo going on my nerves, why could nobody figure that out already?

Answer (score 1):

click by last icon arrow up/down will get checked list of panes, here I can made unchecked Issues pane.

https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/woFGzN93FwR2gCsFM5NoZNatoZ8gbkKlwIuGeHJQvso?feat=directlink

Comment: This hides the error pane once, but it appears again after the next compilation. I want to stop it from appearing.

Comment: Used Qt Creator  3.4.2 (opensource), yes after the next compilation I see that pane show. But it  not active, if was pane [4](Compile Output), pane [1]Issues flashed, but not active if error present in code compilation.

Comment: Right it is not active after the first compilation. But after the second it behaves like I've never disabled it. And disabling it before each compilation is no better than hiding it after every compilation.