# QtCreator: Show compile output instead of Issues, in case of an error

Tags: qt-creator

I could not figure this out so far, but I really prefer to see the actual compile output (and how exactly the compiler was called) instead of the error list in case of a compile or linker error. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a bug in Creator.

There's dedicated preference in: Tools > Options... > Build &Run > General tab > "Open Compile Output pane when building".

But at least in Qt Creator 3.5.1 checking this flag have no sense. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32485547/how-to-disable-the-issues-pane-in-qt-creator).

Comment: I reported it but so far they wont fix it :(

Answer (score 2):

In Qt Creator 4.1.0

Alt. 1:
Window > Output Panes > Compile output

Alt. 2:
At the bar on the botton of the window, you can open a menu where you can enable different output windows. See screenshot.

[image]